# SELECT DISTINCT issue, selecting multiple reservations

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `tblReservation` and `tblBooking`. The `tblReservation` has an `ID` column and an Event Name column. `tblBooking` has it's own `ID` column and has the Reservation ID column as well (foreign key), and then EventStart and EventEnd columns.

Basically I am doing the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    B1.ReservationID,
    B1.EventStart,
    B1.EventEnd,
    tblReservation.EventName
FROM        
    tblBooking AS B1 
INNER JOIN
    tblReservation ON B1.ReservationID = tblReservation.ID
WHERE       
    B1.EventEnd = (SELECT MAX(B2.EventEnd)
                   FROM tblBooking AS B2
                   WHERE B2.ReservationID = B1.ReservationID)
```

I tried this subquery to only pull one Reservation ID per booking. Essentially I want these results:

```
Reservation ID     EventStart    EventEnd     EventName
1                  1/1/18        1/2/18       Event 1
2                  1/2/18        1/3/18       Event 2 
3                  1/4/18        1/6/18       Event 3
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
Reservation ID     EventStart    EventEnd     EventName
1                  1/1/18        1/1/18       Event 1
1                  1/2/18        1/2/18       Event 1
2                  1/2/18        1/2/18       Event 2
2                  1/3/18        1/3/18       Event 2
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for your expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT      
       B1.ReservationID
     , B1.EventStart
     , B1.EventEnd
     , tblReservation.EventName
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B1.ReservationID ORDER BY B1.[EventEnd] DESC) rn
FROM        tblBooking AS B1 
INNER JOIN  tblReservation ON B1.ReservationID = tblReservation.ID
)
SELECT 
       x.ReservationID
     , x.EventStart
     , x.EventEnd
     , x.EventName
FROM X 
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I had thought about using a CTE, but didn't consider the Row_Number Over (Partition By...)

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT(B1.ReservationID), MIN(B1.EventStart) as EventStart, MAX(B1.EventEnd) as EventEnd, Res.EventName
from tblBooking B1
left join tblReservation Res on Res.ID = B1.ReservationID
GROUP BY B1.ReservationID, Res.EventName
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your code. Code only answers are rarely helpful to anyone and are usually deleted.